# What are the number densities of neutrinos and positrons during BBN?

Tags: nucleosynthesis

I'm attempting to work through the third chapter of Dodelson's Modern Cosmology. He gives an approximation for the neutron-proton conversion rate, $\lambda_{\rm np}$ that he lifted from Bernstein, but doesn't give any of the science behind it.

Digging further, I found a [paper](http://www.tapir.caltech.edu/%7Echirata/ph217/lec05.pdf) that derives the rate by first calculating the number densities for neutrinos and positrons:$$n_{\nu_e}=\frac{3\zeta(3)}{4\pi^2}T^3;\quad n_{e^+}=\frac{3\zeta(3)}{2\pi^2}T^3$$
where $\zeta$ is the Riemann zeta function and $\zeta(3)$ is 1.20. This paper then gives examples at $1\,\rm MeV$:$$n_{\nu_e}=1.2\times 10^{31}\, {\rm cm}^{-3};\quad n_{e^+}=2.4\times 10^{31}\, {\rm cm}^{-3}$$
But I can't get the formulas to work. Plugging in $T=1\,{\rm MeV}=1.16\times 10^{10}\,{\rm K}$, I get $$n_{\nu_e}=1.4\times 10^{29}\, {\rm cm}^{-3};\quad n_{e^+}=2.86\times 10^{29}\, {\rm cm}^{-3}.$$
They're off by more than a factor of 100. Are these formulas right? How do I produce the correct number densities of these particles as a function of temperature?

Comment: The  units don't seem to be correct. Temperature does not have the dimensions of inverse length. There must be factors of $k_B$ if you use Kelvin and $\hbar$'s  and $c$'s are  needed somewhere as well.

Comment: I agree. Still trying to work this out. 'Natural Units' are the bane of my existence. Even if you wanted to be lazy and select some unit where the speed of light is 1, you should still include 'c' (or some placeholder) in the formula for the dimensional analysis.

Comment: I recommend you to check out the book of Kolb-Turner : Early Universe, i think they also discuss these things there. At least the lecturer of mine was going trough that book when I studied the BBN.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to include a factor of $(\hbar c)^{-3}$ (that has been set to unity in the paper) and then measure the temperature in Joules.

Notes added after the remark abut units: I think my  units are correct: $\hbar c= 3.16152677...×10^{−26}$ J⋅m so $kT/\hbar c$ has units of
inverse meters.

Including a factor of 2 for the two spin directions and using $p=\hbar k$, we have in detail
$$
N/V=n= 2\times \int \frac{d^3 k}{(2\pi)^3} \frac{1}{e^{|p|c/kT}+1}\\ 
= 2 \frac 1{(2\pi \hbar )^3} \int_0^\infty \frac{4\pi p^2dp} {e^{|p|c/kT}+1}\\
= 2 \frac {(kT)^3}{(2\pi \hbar c )^3} 4\pi \int_0^\infty \frac{x^2 dx}{e^{x}+1}.
$$
I havent worked out the integral for a while, but I think  that it is proprtional to $(7/8)\zeta(3)$.

Comment: Indeed. But then you get the density in $m^{-3}$, not $cm^{-3}$, so you have to divide by $10^6$ to compare to the values quoted in the paper.

Comment: Got it working, thanks!

Comment: Alright, this checks out, except your final expression has an extra factor of 2. It should be $$\frac {(kT)^3}{(2\pi \hbar c )^3} 4\pi \int_0^\infty \frac{x^2 dx}{e^{x}+1}$$

Comment: @Gluon Soup. Is my factor of 2 for spin up/spin down not correct?

Comment: I can't say whether your last formula is correct or not, but it doesn't agree with the paper I cited and once I got the density formulas working, they appear to be giving the right neutron-proton reaction rates.